# $_POST variable from Code Igniter is empty when calling the endpoint with Postman

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, post, postman

I have a web app built with Code igniter, that is working, and want to **be able to call some functions from a certain controller** via postman. 
Because I am using postman (for test purposes), I've ignored the whole login/autentication logic and only focusing on reaching my controller's function. 
The problem is that my `$_POST` (and my `$this->input->post()`) variable is empty when arriving at the controller function. I've tried logging this variable in the `Config.php` file (that I believe is the first file to be called when using Code Ignitier) and it's already empty at that point.

**How am I testing?** 
On my public function, I am printing the result from `$this->input->post()`. The result is empty when calling the function from postman but when I am calling from within my web app the result shows the payload passed through the request. 
From that moment, I went up from the callstack until I reached the `Config.php` file, that's where I tried to print the value from `$_POST`.

I've also tried using `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` but without any success.

My php code:

```
public function myFunction()
    {
        
        $x = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        var_dump($x);
        var_dump($_POST);
        var_dump($this->input->post('payload'));
}
```

In summary:

- Tried diferente type of Content-type with postman (as showm below)
- also tried diferent way to display the post body (as shown above)
- Tried to log the post body in diferent part of the code execution

The request: 
POST: http://localhost/myController/myFunction 
Headers: 
username: my_user

[image]

Result from calling myFunction:

```
NULL
array(0) {}
NULL
```

Why is `$this->input->post()` and `$_POST` empty on that both cases when using postman?

Edit:
As sugested, I've tried using `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` but the result is still the same. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Phil the result is still empty. I"ve tried switching to x-www-form-urlencoded  and form-data and both displayed the same result.

Comment: @Phil i've just updated, thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing the output from your function in the Postman response panel or somewhere else?

Comment: @Phil because I'm logging those output, I can see on the postman panel but I am also using a log_message function that can be called anywhere from the code igniter files. That's why i can use this on the Config.php file.

Comment: @mickmackusa As I said, the web app that use the same route is working perfectly. I call this route thourgh a js file via ajax.

Comment: How is your controller called from javascript?  A relative link or a full url?  I'm trying to rule out path issues because the question body doesn't contain these details.  Have you ever had success (yourself) executing a POST call from Postman to your localhost?

Comment: It a relative link, instead of calling http://localhost/myController/myFunction, I just do /myController/myFunction. I've been able to call a localhost function with postman but it was a GET method and not a POST method.

Comment: You may want to get on the Googles and learn about the intricacies of that.  I saw some discussion @ https://community.postman.com/t/post-to-localhost/13236/7  I am not an authority on such endeavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My case was an issue with the server (nginx) configuration.
When any call hit the endpoint, the server redirected with a 301 status code (I found out about this status code when I used ngrok to provide a public call for the api). 
In Postman, if you use the option `Follow original HTTP Method`, it'll successfully make the request. That's when I noticed that something related to redirected was happening. 
The problem is that 301 redirect doesn't maintain the post body from the request. 
The solution was to update the configuration from the server to redirect with a status code of 307, which will [maintain the post body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307).